# Dynamic Load CSS and JS files

Tags: javascript, css, html, codeigniter

Good day everyone.

I have some questions regarding to dynamic load CSS and JS file.

I know there are a lot of this kind of question around. But what I concerning is:

Should I use back-end program to load CSS and JS?

Example:

```
if($page == "abc.com") {
    echo "<link href='abc.css' />";
else if($page == "def.com") {
    echo "<link href='def.css' />";
else {
    echo "<link href='ghi.css' />";
}
```

Use function load specific CSS in specific page, but it declares inside <body> section.

[Dynamically Add CSS and JS File - CodeIgniter](http://jamshidhashimi.com/2013/04/12/dynamically-add-javascript-and-css-files-in-codeigniter-header-page/)

Inside abc.com

```
add_css(array('metro-admin.css', 'abc.css'));  
echo put_headers();
```

And the source code look like this.

[image]

Comment: Yes, you can use backend to load dynamic css & js files as you are loading based on the urls.

Comment: You could do it this way, but your CSS should be loaded in the `<head>` to avoid possible issues with flashes of unstyled content, and your Javascript should be loaded at the end of your `<body>` to avoid blocking behaviour during the page load. Both of these considerations are ignored by the method used in your question.

Comment: i dont' think this is the good idea. you are trespassing the front-end job. which will be confused when whoever do the maintenence

Comment: @MikeW I'm afraid there is some JS functions might not work properly if I load those javascript files at the end of <body>.

Comment: @Canna Then what should I do?

Comment: Are these actually hosted on different domains? If not, the best answer is to combine them in to one CSS file that the browser can cache.

Comment: Where did you put your put_headers(); call?

Comment: @moebius_eye, Hi moebius_eye. I am so sorry for the late reply. I am too busy recently. I used put_headers() inside the <header> tags. Is that okay?

Comment: You mean the <head> tags, right? And, that's exactly what you should do. I don't think you would have used <header> tags instead of <head> tags, but just in case, check. Maybe that's what you need to fix.

Comment: @moebius_eye, Yeah. I checked. I run these  function inside <head> tags. So everything goes well right?

Answer (score -1):

Ok I have one solution, instead of declaring the css explicitly within PHP, let PHP echo a `<script>` tag in order for PHP to not trespass too much in the front-end.

```
if($page == "abc.com") {
    echo "<script src='abc.js'></script>";
else if($page == "def.com") {
    echo "<script src='def.js'></script>";
else {
    echo "<script src='ghi.js'></script>";
}
```

Ok there's there PHP side done, now we'll crack a script execution within the individual script files.

--== ABC.JS ===--

```
  var includeFiles = [ 
    'abc'
  ];

    for (var i = 0; i < includeFiles.length; i++) {
        $('head').append("<link rel='stylesheet' href=' +includeFiles[i]+ ".css'>");
    }
```

Of course you'd apply round about the same code for each of the files, this will potentially crash in on D.R.Y, but  as this script will only execute if it's explicitly echo'd by PHP, it will not be a repeat, so there's arguments on both sides there.

**Why Use an ARRAY?** Portability, if you wanted to add multiple CSS files per page, then just simple add the CSS file name to the array and the loop will take it on accordingly.

Comment: -1. CSS shouldn't depend on the presence of javascript…

Comment: @moebius_eye That is a rediculous and ambiguous reason to give a -1, what if I wanted to apply a Mobile.CSS when a mobile device is detected on the JS UserAgent, that appends the CSS based on if a Mobile Device is found? A popular way to detect mobile devices and append an overriding CSS stylesheet.

Comment: Then you should use media queries.

Comment: @moebius_eye Ok so based on your logic on Anti-JS to implement CSS, grunt.js shouldn't be automatically appending CSS files? After all, that's what it does.

Comment: I've explained why I don't think this is a good answer. Wether grunt.js does the same mistake is irrelevant. The OP is looking to make the solution he found work properly. Read the comments of his post, and you'll understand why I'm downvoting this.

Comment: This is a legitimate stab at solving the issue, instead of down-voting answers, provide a better one! I don't have issues with down-voting, however done under half-cut knowledge I do have an issue with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54791/discussion-between-raptus-and-moebius-eye).